# iphone 5 retina 4 inch mapview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I'm trying to adapt my app to retina 4 screen for iPhone 5, and adding the png archive and everything resizes but the map view, that moves to the top and leaves a white square on the bottom. I'd like to know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Maybe this has to do with it?

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // We need to manually handle rotation on iPads running iOS 5 and higher to support the new UINavigationBar customization. This is automatic on the iPhone & iPod Touch.
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavBarLandscape@iPad.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavBar@iPad.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
    }
}
else {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 236)];
        [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 236, 480, 32)];
    }
    else {
        [mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372)];
        [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44)];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the to top bar should be anchored to the top. the bottom bars anchored  to the bottom of the controller's view.  The map view should be anchored to the top and the bottom but should also have a vertical spring.

Now everything should expand correctly when you have a iphone 4 or 5.

Also if you are targeting iOS 6, take the time to use AutoLayout.  That way when the iPhoneN has a different resolution you don't have to worry about the layout so much.

Comment: Hi John, I anchored everything as you said... but it didn't change. Also try alutolayout with iOS 6.1...and nothing. Thanks for the advise anyway :)

Comment: I added some code to the question... I think there's the point.

Comment: Well you are hard coding the frames of your UI.  You shouldn't do that.  Since you are targeting iOS 5, you should use springs and struts for this problem.  Or check for iPhone 5 dimensions and change the frame that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check iPhone device version in your code programmatically and resize the controls accordingly.